Correct library for Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject in .Net core 8
Previously, I used Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject with a .NET 4.8 project, but now I have upgraded that project to .NET Core 8. What is the library that supports MSProject?
I want to use MSProject library in .NET core 8 version
Solution :
As @vadim said here Interop service is not working with dotNet core.

Use an External Library (MPXJ)
MPXJ is an open-source library that allows you to read and write Microsoft Project files without depending on the Interop libraries. This library supports several formats including .mpp, .mpx, .xml, and .planner.



using net.sf.mpxj;
using net.sf.mpxj.reader;

public class MSProjectReader
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = new MPPReader();
        ProjectFile project = reader.read("path_to_your_file.mpp");

        foreach (Task task in project.Tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task: {task.Name}, Start: {task.Start}, Finish: {task.Finish}");
        }
    }
}




Have you found any solutions?

@merof I found the solution and I mentioned in the question itself.
Let me know if you want any help in CCPM, CCR

It does not exist. Microsoft.Office.Interop. is used for creating VSTO add-ins. VSTO doesn't work with NET Core and higher (5+).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
